# A moment when I click a notification bar, I want app to capture current screen

Tags: android

A moment when I click a notification bar, I want app to capture current screen. But i want the app capture 'after the notification bar disappears'. And I want that captured screen to be saved and loaded right after and showed up. How shoud i do?

Comment: Could you at least show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example code just do template of "new full screen activity" this will show you how to show/hide toolbar and make full screen.

Then just modify the code so it doesn't happen on a timer, instead move it to a touch listener that you place on the toolbar itself.

Lastly, once the fade has disappeared (which you can do instant if you want) then simply make your own screenshot. There are plenty of great libraries that will do this for you if you want or you can use simple code that I put in a class I named ImageHelper like this:

```
public static Bitmap takeScreenshotOfView(Activity context, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat){
        Bitmap screenshot = null;

    try {
        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = context.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "A35_temp" + File.separator + "screenshot_temp");

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;

        screenshot.compress(compressFormat, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return screenshot;
}
```

And just use it like:

```
Bitmap screenshot = ImageHelper.takeScreenshotOfView(this, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG);
```

Next start a fullScreen Activity new for Preview but default with toolbar hidden and fullscreen ImageView with your share overlay buttons or whatever you want at the bottom.